# Find all triples $(x,y,z)$ of positive integers such that $2018^x=y^2+z^2+1$

Tags: number-theory, sums-of-squares

> Find all triples $(x,y,z)$ of positive integers such that $$2018^x=y^2+z^2+1$$

Comment: Immediately $x$ must be odd

Comment: Why $2018{}{}$?

Comment: Seems like some math contest stuff...

Comment: HINT: Look at this equation modulo $4$. You can easily see that necessarily $x<2$. Then the equation becomes $$z^2+y^2=2017$$ which has only two symmetric solutions $(9,44)$ or $(44,9)$.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Look at this equation modulo $4$. You can easily see that necessarily $x<2$ (i.e. $x=1$).

Then the equation becomes $$z^2+y^2=2017$$ which has only two symmetric solutions $(9,44)$ or $(44,9)$.